# Rails Admin Username and Password once deployed ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-admin

I have finally managed to launch my app after many days of trying but am now facing a problem.

The app uses rails admin to allow an admin user (me hopefully...) to control the objects being output in the app.

However I have pushed the app to Heroku having removed all devise sign up options (I don't want other people to be able to sign up) and as the database has brand new tables and a clean slate, the login details I was using on my localhost are no longer working.

Is there a way for me to create a username and password in my new Heroku database using just the console?

If this isn't the right approach then how can I best set-up my admin user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use console to create new user, it looks like this:

```
> User.create! email: 'foo@example.com', password: 'foobar', confirmation: 'foobar'
```

You can also add this code to `db/seeds.rb` and run rake db:seeds after first deploy (but don't forget to change the password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - would I be required to run the command as follows `heroku run rake db:seeds` with the word `heroku` at the beginning?

Comment: Yep, add that line to the `db/seeds.rb`, push changes to Heroku and then run `heroku run rake db:seeds`.